# Images from Gist not loading in Android Studio using JSON

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, gist

I've created an app in Android Studio and Generated POJO from JSON using Kotlin language and GSON Framework. Here is the link -> [Gist Link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/peymano-wmt/32dcb892b06648910ddd40406e37fdab/raw/db25946fd77c5873b0303b858e861ce724e0dcd0/countries.json).

When I run the app, I am not able to see any of the flag images from the Json link. Does this link require something else in order for the images to show?

I have a recycler view showing the list just fine only the images are not showing. There are no error to report.

Here is my adapter code

```
class CountryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryAdapter.CountryViewHolder>() {

private var countries = listOf<Country>()


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountryViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = ItemCountryBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return CountryViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val country = countries[position]
    holder.bind(country)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countries.size
}

fun setData(countryList: List<Country>) {
    countries = countryList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

inner class CountryViewHolder(private val binding: ItemCountryBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(country: Country) {
        binding.nameTextView.text = country.name
        binding.capitalTextView.text = country.capital
        binding.codeTextView.text = country.code
        Glide.with(binding.flagImageView)
            .load(country.flag)
            .into(binding.flagImageView)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var adapter: CountryAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    adapter = CountryAdapter() // Initialize the adapter

    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CountryViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.countryData?.observe(this, Observer { country ->
        country?.let { countryList ->
            adapter.setData(countryList)
        }
    })

    viewModel.fetchCountryData()
}
```

}